# How to hide panel in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, panel, show-hide

Good day.

I have code:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'test panel',
    html:'test,
    visible: false// did not work
}
```

How to prevent show panel without listeners and controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hidden` config usually is not applied to a part's view, only Sencha knows why.

However, if you want, you can do so with a single line of code in the part's `createView` method. To take your fiddle example:

```
Ext.define('GAINS.parts.ConfigPart', {
    extend: 'Ext.dashboard.Part',
    alias: 'part.config-part',
    config: {
        hidden: false,
        viewTemplate: {
            layout: 'fit',
            mergin: 9
        }

    },
    createView: function (config) {
        var view = this.callParent(arguments);
        view.items = config.configPartItems;
        if(config.hidden) view.hidden = true; // apply the  "hidden" config to the view.
        return view;
    }
});
```

Comment: I already marked as correct previous answer but your solution works! Thank you man. I don't have rate to vote for your answer. I will vote later.

Answer (score 3):

Use the property `hidden` instead:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'test panel',
    html:'test',
    hidden: true // <<== Should works
}
```

Comment: That is true, But maybe you know how hide the same way ConfigPart ?

Comment: @DmitriyZlobenets What do you mean by ConfigPart?

Comment: Could you please take a look here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1o3t

Comment: @DmitriyZlobenets I do not understand your problem. If i uncomment the hidden property in your example it works !

Comment: Yes Its work just for inner Panel but outer panel with title:'Hidden Panel' doesn't hide event if we add hidden:true to parent config. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DmitriyZlobenets Just saw that indeed :) I am trying to find a solution

Comment: @DmitriyZlobenets Can't you add them dynamically instead? That the solution we used for this case.

Comment: You mean on render or boxReady hide the panel ? I think I can do that.